# socket.io Sending a dictionary in Swift does not work

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io

I am having an issue sending dictionaries over socket.io. From what I have read, dictionaries are natively supported and there is no need to first encode to a JSON. I have setup code like so:

```
func configureSockets() {
        // Create a default manager object
        socket = manager.defaultSocket

        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect, callback: {data, ack in
            print("SOCKETS.IO CONNECTED")
        })

        socket.on(clientEvent: .disconnect, callback: {data, ack in
            print("SOCKETS.IO DISCONNECTED")
        })

        socket.onAny({(event) in
            print("any event!!")
        })

        socket.on("chat message", callback: {data, ack in
            print("GOT A CHAT MESSAGE!")
        })

        // Connect to the server
        socket.connect()
    }
```

The setup is done in `viewDidLoad`. I emit the message like so:

```
socket.emit("chat message", ["name": "Bob"])
```

I get nothing back at all when I send a dictionary like above. However sending a string works e.g:

```
socket.emit("chat message", "Hello World!")
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Would really appreciate some feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Same issue here :((